# PrimeFaces.cw does not show dialog content

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When i use `PrimeFaces.cw`..

```
PrimeFaces.cw("Dialog","checkoutDlg",{
  id:"j_idt115",
  draggable:false,
  resizable:false,
  modal:true,
  width:"auto",
  maxWidth: „1083“,
  showEffect:"blind",
  hideEffect:"blind",
  closeOnEscape:true,
  fitViewport:true,
  onShow:function(){
    styleDialogCheckoutBtn()
   }
});
```

..to show a dialog, I just see the lightbox, but the content does not appear.

```
 <p:commandButton id="btnCheckOut" styleClass="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Add to card" process="@this"  
 oncomplete="PrimeFaces.cw('Dialog','checkoutDlg',{ id:'checkoutDlg', draggable:false, resizable:false, modal:true, width:'auto', maxWidth: '1083', showEffect:'blind', hideEffect:'blind', closeOnEscape:true, fitViewport:true, onShow:function(){styleDialogCheckoutBtn()} }); PF('checkoutDlg').initPosition(); PF('checkoutDlg').show(); return false;"/>
```

Dialog content:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="checkoutDlg" id="checkoutDlg">

<div class="cart-items">
    <div class="row-fluid cart-head-row clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="text-bold">#{msg['dashboard.cart.checkout.service']}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="text-bold">#{msg['dashboard.cart.checkout.details']}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            <p class="text-bold">#{msg['dashboard.cart.checkout.price']}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        </div>
</div>

</p:dialog>
```

Can anyone tell me how to show the content of the dialog in the lightbox?

Comment: why do you use it this way?

Comment: because when i use this way `<p:dialog widgetVar="checkoutDlg" closeOnEscape="true" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="blind" width="1083px" height="786px" showHeader="false" 
     modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" closable="false" onShow="styleDialogCheckoutBtn()" fitViewport="true">`

Comment: Sorry I fail to understand this comment

Comment: @kukeltje sorry. hier is the full comment:  because when i declare the dialog like this `<p:dialog widgetVar="checkoutDlg" closeOnEscape="true" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="blind" showHeader="false" modal="true" resizable="false" draggable="false" closable="false" onShow="styleDialogCheckoutBtn()" fitViewport="true"> ... </p:dialog>` and open it when user click on `commandButton`, primefaces add to the dialogbox inline css like "left" or "top" and also some css-classes. this cause some problem for the designer to make the dialogbox responsive. that's why i have to get rid of it.

Comment: Then use jquery to get rid of it